# Round a jagged face by smoothing only the edges tangent to the face

Tags: bevel, smooth

I have a face with jagged edges that I would like to turn into an ellipse by limiting the angle at each vertex in the direction tangent to the face, but keeping the sharp angles normal to the face.

Ideally this smoothing would be accomplished with `proportional editing` so the vertical walls would be also smoothed while keeping the sharp transition between the face and the walls.

I've already tried the `bevel` and `smooth` tools, but those introduced changes beyond the "normal" plane or created 3d peaks all around the face.

Extra info: I want to extrude that face to create a cylindrical pocket inside the part. If I extrude as it is, the cylinder will have jagged walls.
If it's easier to smooth the walls of the cylinder after extruding, that works as well.

[image: Face with jagged edges]

Comment: It might be helpful to people trying to help you if you uploaded an example blend file to the site https://blend-exchange.com and add that link in the question.